# i want to integrate "google sign in" in my google app engine project

Tags: django, google-app-engine, web, webapp2

I want the google sign in method in my webapp2 application. Currently i can't find any method (in google searches) to do that. You can easily do that in javascript (but that's on the client side), i want the data on my server side so i can add user to the database (if not present already). Some example snippets would be great help. and is there official documentation to do that?

i want to do it in a controller like so

```
from google.appengine.api import users
import webapp2
class Google_sign_up(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        # code for the google sign in goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

This documentation [1] should help you. It is part of a multi-page tutorial, so you might want to do the complete tutorial from start as a reference.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/authenticating-users